# Adding labels to outlook calender meeting

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2003

We have exchange 2003, and i would like do add custom labels to the outlook calander when you add a appointment.
I found ways to do this on the client, but i want to add one from the server so every client can use it without having to add it.

I was wondering how i would do this?

Incase i explained it badly, is a screenshot that basicly explains it all.
[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

Labels have been depcrecated in favor of Categories (almost the same thing to begin with). 
Each person's Outlook profile determines what labels/categories they have to pick from. Labels that someone else puts on a shared calendar (or meeting request) will be displayed correctly in the calendar view, but will not be an option for the viewing user.
 If everyone is running Outlook 2007 then you can use GPO to set everyone's categories to the same thing, [Microsoft has a KB Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179073.aspx) on how to do this.

Comment: We have 2003 still sadly. But we are thinking about upgrading so your information will be usefull.
If it was not clear i want to add a new label that everyone can select from in the label list.

Comment: If you're just trying to add one label to everyone's individual settings, that's not supported (except for manually walking around and doing it). I had this exact same situation, maybe in Outlook 2010...